# Detecting difference with route change and url entry

Tags: angular, typescript

I've tried to find but couldn't, so here I am. I wanna learn that if is there any way to detect difference between route change and url entry. I have some scenarios needs to respond differently to **route change** and **url entry - like clicking the link from bookmarks**.

Comment: How is clicking the link from bookmarks and manual url entry even different? Maybe it's just me,  but I would consider it technically the same.

Comment: Those two are the same. It was an example.

Comment: Okay and route change is within Angular then I guess? Maybe Angular has some hook or event on route change (and you have a number  of the change, e.g. you could differ between the first and any one else?).

Comment: I think I can work with that. Thank you @hakre

Comment: Try it, describe how you solved it in an answer and accept your own answer. Q&A style. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something like this in my `app.component`, and it works as intended:

```
changeCount = 0;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.subs.add(this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.changeCount++;

        if (this.changeCount == 1) {
            // do some works
        } else {
            // do some other works
        }
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
      }
    }));
}
```

If `changeCount` **equals to 1**, that means this is the first entry to website, and if it is **greater than 1**, then it means this is a route change.